# Render XML as file, not inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the option in my app to render a XML version of an invoice. To do this, I use a separate class, because it has some complicated calculations. This works fine and it renders the XML nicely in the browser.

However, I prefer to have it downloaded as file instead. How can I achieve this?
In the controller I now have this:

```
def show
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render xml: @invoice.render_xml }
  end
end
```

I know you can add options to get it downloaded:

```
filename: 'mydoc.xml', type: "application/xml", disposition: 'attachment'
```

But how do I combine it with my specific code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `render` in your controller to `send_data`, and add the options that you have in your question. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data